# How to set quicksearch initial value?

Tags: php, user-interface, frameworks, atk4

where I want tu put an initial value.
I have seen that quicksearch has 'q' element but I can't access it, for example this does not find the q element:

```
$quickSearch->getElement('q');
```

How can I access the quicksearch in order to set an initial value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source of it can help you find things out. Agile Toolkit is designed in a way where developer should take advantage of the knowledge of the source code.

QuickSearch is derived from Filter which is derived from Form, so there should be addField somewhere. Looking at the QuickSearch, you'll find it inside recallAll() function. There are no calls to this functions so we should look into the parent class - Filter.

Filter sets up a hook in api to call recallAll after initialization have been finished. That means to be able to access the field you can either redefine a method or add a hook yourself.

**Hook:**

```
$this->api->addHook('post-init',function() use($quickSearch){
    $quickSearch->getElement('q')->set('hello');
});
```

**Extending**

```
class MyQuicksearch extends QuickSearch {
    function recallAll(){
        parent::recallAll();
        $this->getElement('q')->set('hello');
    }
}
```

Finally you can take advantage of knowing where recallAll is loading their default values from and simply do this:

```
$quicksearch->memorize('q','hello');
```

Comment: Thanks again, I ended up using: if($qs->recall('q')==''){
            $qs->memorize('q',$default);
        }

Answer (score 0):

to address this, we must first understand how the Search Field of the QuickSearch Class is added to the Grid Basic Class. so upon investigation of the source code, we can see that:

1. QuickSearch Class does not track (or save a **PUBLIC** reference of) the Form_Field `q`
2. Form_Field `q` is **ONLY** added *DURING* the Rendering phase of the grid

knowing these, we can now proceed adding the modifications to address item #1.

first, we need to add a variable to track the Form_Field `q` in the QuickSearch Class:

```
 var $search_field=null; // add this line (1)
 function recallAll(){
    $ff=$this->addField('line','q','');
    $this->search_field=$ff; // and this line (2)
    parent::recallAll();
    :
    :
 }
```

second, to address item #2, on our page where the grid is defined, we need add a follow-up hook, example:

```
 class page_gridsearchtest extends Page {
    var $search=null;

    function init() {
       parent::init();

       $g = $this->add('MVCGrid');
       $g->setModel('Employees');
       if($g){
          $this->search=$g->addQuickSearch(array('fullname'));
          if($this->search)
             $this->api->addHook('post-init',array($this,'MyHook')); // add hook
       }
    }
    function MyHook(){ // hooked method
       if($this->search->search_field) {
          if($this->search->search_field->get()=='')
             $this->search->search_field->set('Juan'); // set initial search if blank
          $this->search->search_field->setCaption('Employee Name Search');
       }
    }
 }
```

this will set a *CAPTION* beside the QuickSearch field and add a *DEFAULT* search text if the search field is empty.

if this is just a one-time thing, then this may be useful as a quick fix because directly making changes to the library source is very unorthodoxed and does not follow the OOP concept of extending and sub-classing as promoted by ATK.

Comment: btw, the third argument to addHook is priority, which can add a hook which will be executed first, this way you don't need to check for empty value.  Otherwise - awesome answer, you really understand Agile Toolkit, @OT :)